# Redirect all HTTP request to a local webserver using pound and dnsmasq for a wireless accesspoint

Tags: linux-networking

I think it is possible to redirect all requests using pound and dnsmasq for an wireless access point but I must have made a mistake. Here the /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.42.1/24
static domain_name_servers=191.168.42.1
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

Here /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan0      # Use the require wireless interface - usually wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.42.2,192.168.42.20,255.255.255.0,24h
address=/#/192.168.42.1
```

Here is /etc/pound/pound.cfg

```
User            "www-data"
Group           "www-data"
#RootJail       "/chroot/pound"

## Logging: (goes to syslog by default)
##      0       no logging
##      1       normal 
##      2       extended
##      3       Apache-style (common log format)
LogLevel        1

## check backend every X secs:
Alive           30

## use hardware-accelleration card supported by openssl(1):
#SSLEngine      "<hw>"

# poundctl control socket
Control "/var/run/pound/poundctl.socket"


######################################################################
## listen, redirect and ... to:

## redirect all requests on port 8080 ("ListenHTTP") to the local webserver (see "Service" below):
ListenHTTP
   Address 192.168.42.1
   Port    80
   Service
     Redirect "http://192.168.42.1:8080/roomtemp.htm"
   End
End
```

In my browser I can indeed access http://192.168.42.1:8080/roomtemp.htm but if I write anything else nothing is shown. My client get 192.168.42.1 as DNS server as it should. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to enable pound and that is done in /etc/default/pound